# Bootstrap Accordion not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Don't know where I am going wrong. Have been trying to make the accordion work. But it is working correctly on till collapseThree. After that it isn't showing auto collapsing behavior.
Tried almost every way possible to make it work

```
<!-- <p class="narrow" style="text-align: left;"> -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left; border-color: #ffffff !important;">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
<strong> Who are we? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
<div class="panel-body">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
<strong> What we do? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"> </strong>
</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
<div class="panel-body">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
<strong>How we work? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"> </strong>
</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
<div class="panel-body">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> 


<!--     <p class="text-center">
<a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-rounded green"> start using bootsnipp <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
</p> -->
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
<h3 class="head text-center">Trip<span style="color:#4ea647;">Secure</span></h3>
<p class="narrow" style="text-align: left;">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left; border-color: #ffffff !important;">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
<strong> Who are we? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></strong>
</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
<div class="panel-body">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
<strong> What we do? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"> </strong>
</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
<div class="panel-body">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                                                                    <strong>How we work? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></strong>
</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
<div class="panel-body">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</p>
```

Comment: _Emergency?_ call ***100***???

Comment: Can you share a fiddle please!

Comment: recreate at Codepen or jsfiddle needed to understand properly.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to throw a tab-pane inside your according and that is the problem

Comment: Remove `fade` class from `class="tab-pane fade"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your tags elements were not closed. 
Replace this with your code. you were placed the same `id="accordion"` that's why second accordion was not working.

```
<!-- <p class="narrow" style="text-align: left;"> -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left; border-color: #ffffff !important;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <strong> Who are we? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <strong> What we do? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span> </strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    <strong>How we work? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span> </strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--     <p class="text-center">
<a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-rounded green"> start using bootsnipp <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
</p> -->


<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <h3 class="head text-center">Trip<span style="color:#4ea647;">Secure</span></h3>
    <p class="narrow" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left; border-color: #ffffff !important;">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                            <strong> Who are we? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                            <strong> What we do? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span> </strong>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                                <strong>How we work? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <p class="narrow" style="text-align: left;"> -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left; border-color: #ffffff !important;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <strong> Who are we? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <strong> What we do? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span> </strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    <strong>How we work? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span> </strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--     <p class="text-center">
<a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-rounded green"> start using bootsnipp <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
</p> -->


<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <h3 class="head text-center">Trip<span style="color:#4ea647;">Secure</span></h3>
    <p class="narrow" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left; border-color: #ffffff !important;">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                            <strong> Who are we? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                            <strong> What we do? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span> </strong>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default" style="text-align: left !important; border-color: #ffffff!important;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix" style="background: #ffffff!important;">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                                <strong>How we work? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span></strong>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think there is still something wrong with the code